# Memory consumption of JSF 2.0 AJAX frameworks in respect to state holding

Tags: ajax, jsf, session, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am currently maintaining and developing an application (still) based on JSF 1.2, RichFaces 3.3.3 and Seam which makes use of a4j-ajax where applicable.
The problem is, that a4j uses a really memory consuming way of storing the view states in the session (see [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/566937#566937) for example), which quickly hits heap size limitations with many users accessing the site. Sessions quickly grow several MBs in size.

As I am about to upgrade to JSF 2.0, I wonder how well JSF's native ajax implementation handles this. Or are there any alternatives? Is it possible to circumvent the memory issue by switching to a different JSF ajax framework?